Excel: Is there a way for me to use formulas to return the value in a cell using a specific type of two-step search in another sheet?
Suppose I have an Excel file with multiple sheets, and on the main sheet the user can type in a year and a name. I would like to create a formula that returns a code assigned with that name under that year. However, it is not as simple as a 2D table, as neither the names nor the codes are consistent across different years. Instead, every two columns in the second sheet are for each year, and each row is a different person. The left cell is their name and the right cell is their code.
Sheet1
Sheet2



2023


2022


2021






Adeyemi
6433

Adeyemi
8818

Ford
7461



Combs
6453

Combs
6682

Galloway
5320



Galloway
9791

Ford
9039

Lee
7720



Johnson
9615

Lee
7099

Moreno
6014



Lee
9415

Lutz
3694

Pitts
2266



Lutz
9179

Pitts
2254

Rodriguez
2518



Moreno
2374

Rofriguez
4978

Smith
2308



Park
9290

Singh
4081






Pitts
8715

Smith
5503






Singh
8563










I have tried using =INDIRECT() in combination with other formulas, but I need =INDIRECT() to return the reference to a cell, not the value within a cell.

Pls dont post sample data as image. Use Markdown format which can be copied for test. I edit it into your question.

With the use of CHOOSECOLS the formula:
=INDEX(A1:H11,MATCH(L2,CHOOSECOLS(A1:H11,MATCH(L1,A1:H1,0)),0),MATCH(L1,A1:H1,0)+1)
A1:H1 is the row of the years
A1:H11 is the whole range of data
Add the sheetname before the ranges like Sheet1!A1:H11 if table is on another sheet.
L1: The year to search
L2: The name to search

Without CHOOSECOLS use this formula as Rachel commented
=INDEX(A1:H11,MATCH(L2,INDEX(A1:H11,,MATCH(L1,A1:H1,0)),0),MATCH(L1,A1:H1,0)+1)

Thank you for your response, however, I do not have access to CHOOSECOLS, the closest I have is CHOOSE. Is there another way?

@DylanGarcia, you can just replace CHOOSECOLS with INDEX: =INDEX(A1:H11, MATCH(L2, INDEX(A1:H11, , MATCH(L1, A1:H1, 0)), 0), MATCH(L1, A1:H1, 0) + 1). but if you need to do it pre-365 way, then probably just use OFFSET.

I noticed you said you don't have CHOOSECOLS, so I figure you might want the pre-365 OFFSET and VLOOKUP:
=VLOOKUP(L2,OFFSET(A2:H11,,MATCH(L1,A1:H1,0)-1,,2),2,FALSE)
Below use OFFSET to get the name-code table based on your selected year.
=OFFSET(A2:H11, , MATCH(L1, A1:H1, 0) - 1, , 2)
Then you just need to do a VLOOKUP on that range.
